# AWS Elastic Search set schema/mapping for unknown new keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I know we can set the schema for fields that haven't come in yet when we create the index. Is it possible however to set the default schema for unknown fields that can come in into a given index.

Use case:
I have a DynamoDB table contents of which are indexed in AWS Elastic Search instance. DynamoDB table contains identifiers that should not be indexed as text and could receive a new identifier that has not been specified previously by the elastic search schema.

The issue is if a new String field gets set in DynamoDB item it will get indexed in Elastic Search by default as this :

```
 {
  "mappings": {
    "metadata": {
      "properties": {
        "my_new_field": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While I want the new field mapping to default to

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "metadata": {
      "properties": {
        "my_new_field": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use an new dynamic mapping definition specific for certain indexes or document types that you expect to come in.
have a look [here][1] : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html